# BeautifulSoup+HTML+Regex = ...Nothing?

Tags: python, html, regex, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to make a webscraper that gets some information (in this case a phone number). In order to get the phone number, I'm using a self-created and tested regex (using RegExr) to search for the phone number, which is here (accounting for country code (+1 in the USA), parentheses, etc.)

```
regexPhone = re.compile("(\+?1[-.\s]?)?(([0-9]{3}|(\([0-9]{3}\)))[-.\s]?[0-9]{3}[-.\s]?[0-9]{4})|[0-9]{11}|[0-9]{10}|[0-9]{7}")
```

I have a soup object, and go through it like so:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.content, "html.parser")
for num in soup.find_all(regexPhone)
    print num
```

However, even though I **know** there's a phone number within the html page, the program doesn't print it. Why is this, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: You need to escape the backslashes or use a raw string. Read [https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for more information.

Comment: Forget about bs and just run it against request.content (should probably be response.content).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added raw string to regex and extracted only text from `soup` using `soup.get_text()`.

```
regexPhone = re.compile(r"(\+?1[-.\s]?)?(([0-9]{3}|(\([0-9]{3}\)))[-.\s]?[0-9]{3}[-.\s]?[0-9]{4})|[0-9]{11}|[0-9]{10}|[0-9]{7}")

soup = BeautifulSoup(request.content, "html.parser")
text = soup.get_text(strip="True")
results = regexPhone.search(text)
print(results.groups())
```

Comment: I'm using Python 2.x, so I had to change     regexPhone.search(text) to regexPhone.findall(text) and went from there, but thanks!